# Use tidyverse to find time-series means of cross-sectional correlations

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to find the time-series mean of annual cross-sectional correlations.

Before `tidyverse`, I would:

1. convert `dat` to a list of annual data frames
2. use `lapply()` to find the annual cross-sectional correlations
3. use `Reduce()` to find the means manually

This logic works, but is not `tidy`.

```
set.seed(2001)
dat <- data.frame(year = rep(2001:2003, each = 10),
                  x = runif(3*10))
dat <- transform(dat, y = 5*x + runif(3*10))
dat_list <- split(dat[c('x', 'y')], dat$year)
dat_list2 <- lapply(dat_list, cor)
dat2 <- Reduce('+', dat_list2) / length(dat_list2)
dat2

##           x         y
## x 1.0000000 0.9772068
## y 0.9772068 1.0000000
```

For a `tidyerse` solution, my best (and failed) attempt is to:

1. `group_by()` the `year` variable
2. use `do()` and `cor()` each year
3. use `map()` and `mean()` to find elementwise means

This logic fails and returns `NULL`.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  do(cormat = cor(.$x, .$y)) %>% 
  map(.$cormat, mean)
dat2

## $year
## NULL
## 
## $cormat
## NULL
```

Is there a `tidyverse` idiom to replace the `Reduce()` idiom in my non-`tidyverse` solution above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  do(correl = cor(.data[c('x', 'y')])) %>% 
  {reduce(.$correl, `+`)/nrow(.)}



          x         y
x 1.0000000 0.9772068
y 0.9772068 1.0000000
```

Note that this is exactly the same as `cor(dat[c('x', 'y')])`, so unless you need the matrices for each year individually there's no need to group by year and then reduce. This also holds for >2 variables.

Comment: Will this work with 3+ variables? I should have given an example of 3+ variables.

Comment: Edited for the >2 variable case